# CentOS: E-mail notification of failed ssh login attempts

Tags: security, centos, ssh, bash, scripting

Under CentOS, I need a script that will run every 10 minutes and e-mail me if there are any new failed ssh login attempts in /var/log/secure.

Comment: Just my thoughts; This would be a bad idea if this is on a public facing machine that allows anyone to connect to SSH. You will be swamped with emails due to automated attacks.

Answer (score 4):

Why not considering to use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [SSHGuard](http://www.sshguard.net/). Fail2ban seems configurable to send emails. These are better than any script written within 5 or 10 minutes.

Also, such solutions can protect you other than just sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Logcheck](http://logcheck.org/) for "analysing" specific logs and it sends periodically emails to you. Of course, some configuration is necessary.
On Debian systems installed via aptitude install logcheck it checks /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log per default. But adding other logs and configuration the search strings via RegEx (?) is kind of easy.

Please read the notice on the download page:

> Note: For installation on platforms other than Debian, download the latest tarball using the  source package links found on the [logcheck package page](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/logcheck)